# JavaScript: Simple Async Issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So I'm somewhat new to asynchronous JavaScript, and I can't figure out why the '.2's are logging before the '.1's.

The only asynchronous method here is `makePokemon()`

My goal is that all the '.1's log before the '.2's. thanks

```
                sender.room().forEach(async (client) => {
                    const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
                    client.setPokemon(pokemon);
                    console.log('.1');
                });
                sender.room().forEach(client => {
                    console.log('.2');
                    client.emit('redirect', {
                        yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
                        theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Your first callback function is equivalent to `(client) => { makePokemon(client.getPokemon()).then((pokemon) => { client.setPokemon(pokemon); console.log('1.'); }); }`

Comment: I think this will do exactly what you want:
`const AsyncAF = require('async-af');

AsyncAF(sender.room()).forEachAF(async (client) => {
  const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
  client.setPokemon(pokemon);
  console.log('.1');
  console.log('.2');
  client.emit('redirect', {
    yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
    theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
  });
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that when using `forEach()` in the browser, the expectation is that the callback will execute synchronously.

You could however revise your code as follows (provided the parent function is declared `async`):

```js
/* 
The following changes require the calling function to be async

async function foo() { */

/* Express iteration with for..of to achieve desired behavior */
for(const client of sender.room()) {
  
  const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
  client.setPokemon(pokemon);
  console.log('.1');

}

for(const client of sender.room()) {
  console.log('.2');
  client.emit('redirect', {
    yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
    theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
  });
}

/* } */
```

Alternatively, as Patrick Roberts points out, you could express this logic in part with `Promise.all()`. One advantage with this approach is it allows multiple `async` tasks (ie `makePokemon`) to be dispatched at once rather than in a sequential fashion (as is the case above):

```js
/* Map each client to a promise and execute all with Promise.all() */
Promise.all(sender.room().map(async(client) => {
  const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
  client.setPokemon(pokemon);
  console.log('.1');
}))
/* If all prior promises are resolved, continue with next iteration */
.then(() => {

    for (const client of sender.room()) {
      console.log('.2');
      client.emit('redirect', {
        yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
        theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
      });
    }
})
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use `for...of`. Rather, you should `await Promise.all(sender.room().map(async (client) => ...))` to avoid making the loop in the question sequential instead of parallel. Also, code snippets are for complete examples. It's not very helpful to click "Run code snippet" and immediately get some sort of error.

Comment: I would advice against using `Promise.all` in cases where you don't know how many promises you are going to create for example... Also, it's easier to debug when you are doing a for loop when having issues. As much as Node's async handling should be good I prefer to control the flow myself... maybe it's just a me thing

Comment: @Odinn if `makePokemon()` took even 1/10th of a second to execute, this answer would take 10 seconds to run for 100 clients, while using `Promise.all()` would still allow it to complete in close to 1/10th of a second.

Comment: Don't forget that node is single threaded... Promise all help when you have event loop blocking from io or something of that sort and such to switch between the different executions but I'm not sure it will actually work as well as you described... For my knowledge at least...

Comment: @Odinn your knowledge is flawed. async functions are non-blocking, and awaiting them suspends execution of the control flow, it doesn't block the thread. It works exactly as I described.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for you input - very good point, I've extended the answer. Thank you again :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  i didn't mean that async functions are blocking... i meant that if you execute 10 functions in Promise.all I don't think that you will get such good improvements... But as I mentioned before, it is easier to debug code and probably handle errors and such... Also, if inside Promise.all you initiate socket connections or things like that I rather have control over it with something like pMap.

Comment: @Odinn [it's definitely in the ballpark](https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/fsmr8xtb/), even when taking into account "initiating socket connections". Maybe you want to reconsider your claim.

Comment: It's not really related to this question, however @PatrickRoberts you are actually not correct about async functions being non-blocking. I suggest you read this article: https://medium.com/@michael.gokhman/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io-8c416d76daa3

Comment: @michaelgo in that article, `hash.update()` is a synchronous function. The problem is unrelated to the `async` function wrapping it. You're conflating "non-blocking" with "concurrent". Async functions do not magically run code in separate threads, but the `await` operator does not block the thread, it suspends the execution of the asynchronous function and yields to the caller.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm sorry I think we are saying the same thing, your example makes sense.. I didn't say it's not improving the runtime of things, especially in cases like you just showed where I did say that it can help... But there is more to consider than just speed of execution... That's what I'm saying... In any case this is getting off topic and I'm not sure I'm explaining myself in the right words... My bigger problem with Promise.all were the other things and not the speed it can give you.

Comment: @Odinn We're not saying the same thing at all. "Other things" like debugging? That was the only other point you brought up besides "I don't think that you will get such good improvements", so yes you did say, multiple times in fact, that it wouldn't improve the runtime of things. I also fail to see how `Promise.all(array.map(fn))` prevents you from debugging anything you couldn't debug with `for (const value of array) await fn();` You can set a breakpoint in the body of `fn` either way and inspect individual iterations independently of each other, even when invoking them in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Try waiting on all the promises:

```
            const promises = sender.room().map(async (client) => {
                const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
                client.setPokemon(pokemon);
                console.log('.1');
            });
            await Promise.all(promises);
            sender.room().forEach(client => {
                console.log('.2');
                client.emit('redirect', {
                    yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
                    theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` won't wait for each loop to finish, it simply fires off a bunch of promises. If you want to explicitly wait for all those promises to finish before the second loop starts you can use `map` followed by `Promise.all`. The `map` will return an array of promises. `Promise.all` will explicitly pause until all promises in the given array have resolved. Does something like this work?

```js
// use `map` and capture each promise in a new array
const pokemonPromises = sender.room().map(async (client) => {
  const pokemon = await makePokemon(client.getPokemon());
  client.setPokemon(pokemon);
  console.log('.1');
});

// explicitly wait for all promises to finish before continuing.
await Promise.all(pokemonPromises);

// Continue with non async stuff
sender.room().forEach(client => {
  console.log('.2');
  client.emit('redirect', {
    yourPokemon: client.getPokemon(),
    theirPokemon: client.getOpponent().getPokemon()
  });
});
```

Comment: is it ever better to use forEach instead of map, given that map can return these promises?

Comment: This is exactly the same as [sroes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437081/1541563).